# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256

Tags: encryption, java-8, web3js

When using web3j java library in a spring boot application, I am getting the below exception in the Web3j.build line. Any idea to fix this issue?

private static final Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/sdas"));

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    at org.web3j.protocol.http.HttpService.<clinit>(HttpService.java:37)
    at sg.com.paloit.hashit.service.ContractService.<clinit>(ContractService.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1147)
    ... 48 common frames omitted


 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
     <artifactId>core</artifactId>
     <version>4.1.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: That's a relatively new cipher suite, make sure your Java runtime etc. is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

org.web3j (4.1.0) core comes with lower version of okhttp which doesn't have the cipher: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256.

Its a relatively new cipher, changing okhttp to okhttp3 helped to resolve the issue.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
                        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
```